# WooCommerce REST API - Filter orders by custom field

Tags: woocommerce, advanced-custom-fields, woocommerce-rest-api

I am using WooCommerce and Advanced Custom Fields for the orders. Is there a way to filters orders using the WooCommerce REST API by a custom field?

I want to GET orders that have a specific custom field with a specific value.

Thank you.